# How to pas data between view controller without using segue in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

Helo all,

I am moving from one view controller to another using below code.

```
UIStoryboard  *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RoloBusinessCard"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Now i want to pass some data from one view controller to another like some variable.I have got this code to do this task but i am not making instance of another view controller.I am starting another view controller using storyboard.

```
SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
secondViewController.str1 = str;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
```

Please tell me how can i pass data between view controllers in my way?

**Solution does not work**
decalre  `NSString` in `.h` file.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *UserId;
```

**Synthesize in .m file**

```
@synthesize UserId;
```

**Code for navigation**

```
 UIStoryboard  *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RoloBusinessCard"];
  vc.UserId=@"abc";
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

But `vc.UserId` does not recognized.

Comment: Please try to google before asking questions. Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Like this, Hope it will work.

```
UIStoryboard  *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
SecondViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RoloBusinessCard"];
vc.str1 = str;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass data between two ViewControler with the help of properties.
First in RoloBusinessCard.h ViewControler make a property like this

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *str1;
```

in .m file of this class synthesize it like this

```
@synthesize str2;
```

Now like this you can pass value

```
UIStoryboard  *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RoloBusinessCard"];
vc.str2=str2
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

If you are not able to get str2 in RoloBusinessCard

First  Replace  UIViewController with Your Viewcontroller Name like this

```
RoloBusinessCard *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RoloBusinessCard"];
```

or

typecase UIViewController like this

```
UIStoryboard  *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RoloBusinessCard"];

(RoloBusinessCard *)vc1=vc
    vc1.str2=str2
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc1 animated:YES];
```

Hope it help.

Comment: Not able to get 'str1' as string in my view controller.I have made it property & also synthesize it.But it does not work for me.@chakshu

Comment: edited my answer please check.If you find it correct please accept my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here we are just using Navigation stack for passing data to the next controller

create a property in 2nd view controller

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *yourString;
```

in firstView controller action method 
object of view controller which you will create on push method do

```
-(void)btnAtion{
object.yourstring = txtyourfirstvcObject.text
}
```

In swift, we can do the same

let's suppose we want to pass a Bool Value to the next controller so we can do :

```
Class ToViewController : UIViewController {
      public var isSelected : Bool? 
}

Class FromViewController : UIViewController {

    @IBAction func onClickFlyingFrom(_ sender: UIButton) {
         let tvc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ToViewController") as! ToViewController
         tvc.isSelected = true
         self.navigationController?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```